# How to find one corner of an equilateral triangle in an cartesian system

Tags: geometry, triangles

How to find the coordinates of one corner of an equilateral triangle in an cartesian system if I know the coordinates of the other two corners and the $h$ (altitude)?
I need the simplest solution of them all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the system of the equations of the two circles centered at one point and passing through the other:
$$
\begin{cases}
(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2\\
(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2\\
\end{cases}
$$